# Swift UIActivityViewController Image Share not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share image. After the WhatsApp recent changes to allow share i am able to see WhatsApp in the share option. I am sharing an image and message, I can see the text message but i am not able to share images. The same code works fine with Viber, FB, twitter etc., Not sure what i am missing for WhatsApp.

```
func shareImage() {
    var messageStr:String  = "Check out my awesome photo!"
    var img: UIImage = currentPhoto!

    var shareItems:Array = [img, messageStr]

    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: WhatsApp FAQ http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: I hope these are the earlier techniques, I wanted to use the iOS 8 share extension WhatsApp introduced last week. My issue is I am able share the messageStr but not the UIImage img.

Comment: It seems to be able to share image only when 'shareItems' array contains 'img' only. So I think it's up to WhatsApp.

Comment: Thanks let me try this.

Comment: Perfect thanks Satachito. Looks like WhatsApp is not supporting Array with both text and image. Posing the change that worked for me.

Comment: Hi @DineshJeyasankar , when I shared the png image with transparent background, whatsapp added black mask background to my image. Is there any way around it to remove such or I have to add white background myself? Just asking for your thoughts before moving to adding white background. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To share **Text || Image** try this **Swift**.

```
func share(shareText shareText:String?,shareImage:UIImage?){

    var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()

    if let shareTextObj = shareText{
        objectsToShare.append(shareTextObj)
    }

    if let shareImageObj = shareImage{
        objectsToShare.append(shareImageObj)
    }

    if shareText != nil || shareImage != nil{
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        print("There is nothing to share")
    }
}
```

To share just call like this:

```
let imageToShare = UIImage(named: "myImage")
share(shareText: "Sharing this text", shareImage: imageToShare)
```

Comment: Suggestion: Change `shareText != nil || shareImage != nil` to `objectsToShare.count > 0`

Comment: Zaid Pathan --- not working for me its only share text or only share image not both ... i have tried with facebook & whatsapp too

Comment: @bLacKhoLE
Can you check both `shareText`, `shareImage` are not nil?

Comment: @ZaidPathan yes, they are not nil, i searched for same and found that whatsapp not support Image+Text. you can do this on few apps like imessage, email. thanks for support.

Comment: @ZaidPathan can you only share `UIImage`? Because I have metadata attached to the image file that gets stripped out when the impoverished `UIImage` is created. Can I share the actual image file? Thanks.

Comment: Never-mind, I got it. You have to read in the binary content of the file.

Comment: I am trying to Post my image on Facebook using UIActivityViewController, not working using above code. Please suggest.

Comment: I tried the above code for sharing image and text over whatsapp, but only the text is being shared. Any update on this ?

Answer (score 24):

It seems like WhatsApp shares image only when the array contains images and not combination of both image and text.

```
func shareImage() {
    //var messageStr:String  = "Check out my awesome iPicSafe photo!"
    var img: UIImage = currentPhoto!
    //var shareItems:Array = [img, messageStr]
    var shareItems:Array = [img]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add both  .??

Comment: No. That's how it works with whatsApp now. They may change it in the future.

Comment: I want to share the logo of my app but the image increases and sometimes get cut too. Is there any size for the image while sharing for facebook / whatsapp / twitter / mail ??

Comment: I am trying to Post my image on Facebook using UIActivityViewController, not working using above code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 use this code

```
 @IBAction func whatsappShareWithImages(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {

        let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {

                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {

                    if let image = UIImage(named: "whatsappIcon") {
                        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
                            let tempFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")
                            do {
                                try imageData.write(to: tempFile, options: .atomic)
                                self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile)
                                self.documentInteractionController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                                self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)

                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // Cannot open whatsapp
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Add this code in your app "plist"

```
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
```

You can also refer to small app for reference : https://github.com/nithinbemitk/iOS-Whatsapp-Share