# UIImageView share with UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have this code for get my image

```
imgurl.image = UIImage.init(ciImage: transformedImage)
```

the image great show in device now I want to share this image with UIActivityViewController

here is my code

```
 if (self.imgurl.image == nil) {
            NSLog("image not available.")
            return
        }

        else
        {

            let activityItem: [AnyObject] = [self.imgurl.image as AnyObject]

            let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItem as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

            self.present(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

but after try to share I received this error for Email :

**[MFMailComposeInternalViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.'**

**and for Whats app I received this item cannot be shared.Please select a different item**

is it need to save the image in document directory and need to get from document directory if yes I can't write a code too for saving.

Comment: debug the code and make sure the "activityItem" array has items and not empty. Also you can check the accepted answer for the question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002839/swift-uiactivityviewcontroller-image-share-not-working]

Comment: @user3601599 I check the item its not empty looking my code

Comment: try to convert activityItem to [Any] instead of [AnyObject]

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz isn't work too If I need to save the image in document directory ?

Comment: @MidDev you mean the save image option in the ActivityViewController?

Comment: @user3601599 I can't save this uiimageview any where and data in uiimageview its null but I see the image in uiimageview

Comment: @MidDev try the code with normal image from your assets catalog if it work fine, the problem will be in your transformedImage

Comment: @MidDev Facing same issue. Have you found any solution for this? Any help will be appreciated.